# Problem with dynamic size array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to develop my own game engine running on JavaScript for text adventure games. It's more of a personal project than actually trying to go anywhere with it, but none the less, I am having fun.

The problem I am currently getting is `Uncaught TypeError: optionGroups[(num + 1)] is undefined` from my console, as well as a reference to line 97 in filereader.js. I believe that this is because of how I am defining the array, or trying to use it, but I am also unsure of the "correct" way to do so.

My filereader.js file

```
var raw;

function initFileReader(){
    document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
}

function handleFileSelect(event){
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = handleFileLoad;
    reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0])
}

function handleFileLoad(event){
    //console.log(event.target.result);
    raw = event.target.result;

    //All save files should be marked with MSF somewhere in the file.
    if (!raw.includes("MSF")){
        alert("Not a Save File");
    }
    else{
        
        /*
        * SYNTAX FOR SAVE FILE
        * ===========================================================
        * startupMessage    =   <T><T>
        * optionText        =   <"0"><"0"> where 0 is the index of the entry.
        * optionAddition    =   <'0'><'0'> where 0 is the index of the entry.
        * optionGroups      =   <:0:>1,2<:0:> where 0 is the index of the group, and 1,2 is the list of the entries separated by commas
        * ===========================================================
        * Overrides are done by the last conflicting thing in the file being chosen.
        * Important sections of the text are denoted by <!><!> and will show up as blue text.
        */
        var buffer = raw;
        //Pulling out the startup message.
        buffer = buffer.substring(buffer.search("<T>") + 3);
        startupMessage = buffer.substring(0, buffer.search("<T>"));
        buffer = buffer.substring(buffer.search("<T>") + 3);
        buffer = buffer.trim();
        startupMessage = startupMessage.replace(/<!>/g, "<a class=\"important\">");
        startupMessage = startupMessage.replace(/<\/!>/g, "</a>");
        bodyText += startupMessage;
        
        buffer = buffer.replace(/<!>/g, "<a class=\"important\">");
        buffer = buffer.replace(/<\/!>/g, "</a>");
        
        //Start segment parting
        //console.log(buffer);
        while(buffer != "" || buffer){
            switch(buffer.charAt(1)){
                case '\"':
                //console.log("optionText");
                var num = Number(buffer.substring(2).substring(0, buffer.substring(2).search("\"")));
                //console.log(num);
                buffer = buffer.substring(3).substring(buffer.substring(3).search(">") + 1);
                //console.log(buffer);
                var temp = buffer.substring(0, buffer.search("<\"" + num + "\">"));
                //console.log(temp);
                buffer = buffer.substring(temp.length + ("<\"" + num + "\">").length + 2);
                //console.log(buffer);
                //console.log(""+ num + " : " + temp);
                
                optionText[num] = temp;
                
                break;
                case '\'':
                //console.log("optionAddition");
                var num = Number(buffer.substring(2).substring(0, buffer.substring(2).search("\'")));
                //console.log(num);
                buffer = buffer.substring(3).substring(buffer.substring(3).search(">") + 1);
                //console.log(buffer);
                var temp = buffer.substring(0, buffer.search("<\'" + num + "\'>"));
                //console.log(temp);
                buffer = buffer.substring(temp.length + ("<\'" + num + "\'>").length + 2);
                //console.log(buffer);
                //console.log(""+ num + " : " + temp);
                
                optionAddition[num] = temp;
                
                break;
                case ':':
                //console.log("optionGroups");
                var num = Number(buffer.substring(2).substring(0, buffer.substring(2).search(":")));
                //console.log(num);
                buffer = buffer.substring(3).substring(buffer.substring(3).search(">") + 1);
                //console.log(buffer);
                var temp = buffer.substring(0, buffer.search("<:" + num + ":>"));
                //console.log(temp);
                buffer = buffer.substring(temp.length + ("<:" + num + ":>").length + 2);
                //console.log(buffer);
                //console.log(""+ num + " : " + temp);
                
                let nums = temp.split(",");
                console.log(Number(nums[0]));
                console.log(optionGroups);
                for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i){
                    optionGroups[num+1][i] = Number(nums[i]);
                    ++i;
                }
                console.log(optionGroups);
                break;
            }
        }
        
        
        
        var el = document.getElementById("gameSelectionWrapper");
        var opacity = 1.0;
        var fade = setInterval(() =>{
            if(opacity <= 0){
                el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
                clearTimeout(fade);
            }
            else {
                opacity = opacity - 0.02;
                el.style.opacity = opacity;
            }
        }, 30/1000);
        createSelections(0);
    }
}
```

My index.js file

```
var bodyText = "";
var prevBodyText = bodyText;
var optionText = [];
var optionAddition = [];
var currentOptionGroup = 0;
var optionGroups = [];
var startupMessage = "";

function startup(){
    initFileReader();
    mainLoop();
}

function mainLoop(){
    setInterval(()=>{
        updateText();
        prevBodyText = bodyText;
    }, 30/1000);
}


function updateText(){
    if(prevBodyText != bodyText){
        let body = document.getElementById("bodyTextWrapper");
        body.innerHTML = bodyText;
        body.scrollTop = body.scrollHeight;
        console.log(">> Updated Body Text");
    }
}

function selectionHandler(flag){
    for(let i = 0; i < optionGroups[currentOptionGroup].length; ++i){
        removeOption(optionGroups[currentOptionGroup][i]);
    }
    createSelections(flag+1);
    currentOptionGroup = flag + 1;
    bodyText += "<br><br>" + optionAddition[flag];
}

function removeOption(optionNum){
    var el = document.getElementById("option" + optionNum);
    if(el != null){
        var opacity = 1.0;

        var fade = setInterval(() =>{
            if(opacity <= 0){
                el.parentNode.removeChild(el);

                clearTimeout(fade);
            }
            else {
                opacity = opacity - 0.05;
                el.style.opacity = opacity;
            }
        }, 30/1000);
    }
}

function createSelections(setNumber){
    for(var e in optionGroups[setNumber]){
        createOption(optionGroups[setNumber][e]);
    }
}

function createOption(optionNum){
    console.log("Making option");
    var div = document.createElement("DIV");
    div.className = "selection";
    div.setAttribute("onclick", "selectionHandler("+optionNum+");");
    div.id = "option" + optionNum;
    div.innerHTML = ">> " + optionText[optionNum];
    div.style.opacity = 0.0;
    document.getElementById("selectionWrapper").appendChild(div);
    
    var opacity = 0;
    setTimeout(() => {
        var fade = setInterval(() => {
            if(opacity >= 1){
                clearTimeout(fade);
                
            }
            else {
                opacity = opacity + 0.05;
                div.style.opacity = opacity;
            }
        }, 30/1000);
    }, 400);
}
```

My sample save file

```
MSF
<T>Hello and welcome. <!>Please</!> press <!>Start</!> to begin.<T>
<"0">Start<"0">
<'0'>You have started the game.<'0'>
<:0:>1,2<:0:>
<"1">Go Left<"1">
<'1'>Heading left.<'1'>
<"2">Go Right<"2">
<'2'>Heading right.<'2'>
```

Please let me know if you need to see anything else, I would really appreciate any feedback on this one.

Comment: You cannot assign to `optionGroups[num+1][i]` unless `optionGroups[num+1]` exists; a quick fix is to do `if (!optionGroups[num+1]) optionGroups[num+1] = [];` first.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much!